# output files from a function Python

Tags: python, function

I have a file named "file.txt" and I want to write my first part of the program to have a function to first output 2 files.
my code:

```
f = open("file.txt", "r+")
def Filter_NoD(f):
     """this function filters out lines with no D region and saves them in a separate file"""
     lines = open(f, "r+").read().splitlines()
     NoD = open("NoD.txt", "w")
     withD = open("withD.txt", "w")
     for i, line in enumerate(lines):
          if ">No D" in line:
          NoD.write(lines[i-2]+"\n"+lines[i-1]+"\n"+lines[i])
          else:
          withD.write(line+"\n")
    return NoD, withD
```

I can't output 2 files, NoD.txt and withD.txt, I also tried with out the return statement and there was still no output files.
what am i doing wrong?

Comment: What do you mean you cannot output 2 files?...did u get errors?...or are the files empty?...If it's the latter then that's probably because you didn't close the files..(`NoD.close()` and `withD.close()`)..but if it's the former then post the traceback error message

Comment: The code you posted works for me. Did you get an error? Edit your question to include it. Perhaps the problem is how you called your function. I will note that you have a global variable named `f`, then you also have an argument to your function named `f`, which can be confusing. Your global `f` is a file, and your argument `f` is a string (the path to a file).

Comment: I recommend using a [`with` statement](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/compound_stmts.html#the-with-statement) to handle closing the files automatically on success or error.

Comment: Which parameter are you using when calling `Filter_NoD()`? Or are you even calling `Filter_NoD`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, your indentation is wrong.

Second, you pass `f` into the `def` but it seems that `f` is a file handler so you cant open it again inside the definition.

Here is a working code:

The content of `file.txt`:

```
asd
>No D bsd
csd
```

The code:

```
f = open("file.txt", "r+")
def Filter_NoD(f):
    """this function filters out lines with no D region and saves them in a separate file"""
    lines = f.read().splitlines() # As f is already a file handler, you can't open it again
    NoD = open("NoD.txt", "w")
    withD = open("withD.txt", "w")
    for i, line in enumerate(lines):
        if ">No D" in line:
            NoD.write(lines[i-2]+"\n"+lines[i-1]+"\n"+lines[i])
        else:
            withD.write(line+"\n")
    return NoD, withD

Filter_NoD(f) # Dont forget to call the function, and that you pass a file handler in
```

After the run the content of `NoD.txt`:

```
csd
asd
>No D bsd
```

And the content of `withD.txt`:

```
asd
csd
```

Answer (score 1):

You never call the actual function.

Answer (score 1):

When I copy and paste your function `Filter_NoD` above and call it on some file I wrote some gibberish in called `file.txt`:

```
some
stuff
inasd
this
file
>No D
sthaklsldf
```

I get two files output, `NoD.txt` and `withD.txt` that contain the expected output. Which confirms my suspicion that your code is mostly correct.

So, I would guess one of a couple things are happening:

1. You're not looking in the correct folder where you are calling the python program, so the files are being saved, just not where you're looking.
2. Are you getting any errors from the python interpreter? I ask because in the code snippet you gave, `f = open("file.txt", "r+")`, is right above the function definition of `Filter_NoD`. Are you calling `Filter_NoD` with a file object (`f`) instead of a file path, which is what `Filter_NoD` expects? If so, the program errors out and nothing with be written.

Aside from the above, you need to be careful with the way you're opening file objects. It's much safer to scope an open file within a `with` block, like:

```
    def Filter_NoD(f):
        lines = open(f, "r+").read().splitlines()
        with open("NoD.txt", "w") as NoD:
            with open("withD.txt", "w") as withD:
                for i, line in enumerate(lines):
                    if ">No D" in line:
                        NoD.write(lines[i-2]+"\n"+lines[i-1]+"\n"+lines[i])
                    else:
                        withD.write(line+"\n")
```

If you do it this way, then the files will automatically close when you exit the function.